# SimpleMessageListenerContainer ChannelTransacted and MaxConcurrentConsumers

Tags: transactions, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm trying to configure a SimpleMessageListenerContainer from Spring AMQP with channeled transactions to dynamically add consumers on demand. The problem is, I don't see consumers being added dynamically when I have a channeled transaction. To be clear, this doesn't dynamically add consumers under load:

```
container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
container.setChannelTransacted(true);
container.setTransactionManager(rabbitTransactionManager);
```

But this does:

```
container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
//container.setChannelTransacted(true);
//container.setTransactionManager(rabbitTransactionManager);
```

My questions are:

1. Why aren't the consumers being added dynamically?
2. Is there  a workaround to get both channeled transactions and dynamic consumers to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's a bug - please open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).
2. There is not a workaround, unfortunately; it needs a patch.

The use of transactions with RabbitMQ is quite rare, especially on the consumer side - can you explain why you need them?

Comment: Thank you for opening the issue. My team is using them because we thought they help mitigate message loss. Is there a better strategy you suggest?

Comment: You do not need transactions on the consumer side to avoid message loss; on the consumer side, transactions only apply to the ack, not the delivery of the message itself. There is no danger of losing messages, even without transactions, since they are only removed from the queue when the ack is received (that is, when you use AUTO ackmode - the default - you *can* lose messages if you use AckMode NONE - called autoAck in rabbit-speak). You can read [all about transactions in the RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html).

Comment: That's good to know. So I probably won't need the transactions anyways. Thanks!